# Save List<> in .txt file

Tags: c#, file, save

I am actually learning c# and have problem with saving my List<> to the file. I spent several hours searching for answer, but I didn’t find it (maybe I was looking wrong) . I have ”CS0030 C# Cannot convert type to 'string'“ error (and foreach loop is marking this error). 
Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong or give me some advices?
Thanks

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "*.txt";
            dlg.DefaultExt = "txt";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Stream fileStream = dlg.OpenFile();
                TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

                foreach(string s in list2)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(s);
                }
            writer.Close();
            }
            dlg.Dispose();
        }
```

list2 is a copy of list1, where user has added some elements.

Comment: How are List1 & List2 declared?  Lists of what?

Comment: how about json serialization? might want to try.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

Comment: We need information about what is a type of your list.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `list2` is defined as `List<SomeClass>` you have to explicitly specify type in foreach like `SomeClass s` or use `var s` and let compiler determine it.

```cs
// or foreach(SomeClass s in list2)
foreach(var s in list2)
{
   writer.WriteLine(s);
}
```

--Edit

[TextWriter.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.writeline?view=netcore-3.1) has quite many overloads and when you specify an [object it will call internally its toString() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.writeline?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_TextWriter_WriteLine_System_Object_) and that might be not what you want.

Number of overloads depends on .NET Framework/.NET Core version of course.

Comment: That won't help since `WriteLine` takes a string, you've just moved the problem to inside the loop body.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Yes, but without an overriden ToString() it will just show the Type name. OP has to give more information.